# Static and get set method problems

Tags: java, static, get, set

Okay, it might sounds silly, but I really don't know what is going on here. So firstly,

```
System.out.print("\nPlease enter your name :");
Member.setName(scChar.nextLine());
System.out.print("\nPlease enter your age :");
Member.setAge(scInt.nextInt());
System.out.print("\nPlease enter your I/C number :");
Member.setIcNo(scChar.nextLine());
System.out.print("\nPlease enter your phone number :");
Member.setPhoneNo(scChar.nextLine());
System.out.print("\nPlease enter your address :");
Member.setAddress(scChar.nextLine());
```

When I run using Jcreator LE, it says that my setName is not a static so I have to change to static and now every of my variables is static.

```
private static String name;
private static int age;
private static String icNo;
private static String phoneNo;
private static String address;
private static java.util.Date date;
private static java.util.Date expiryDate;
private static int trialClass = 0;
private static double joiningFees = 80.00;
private static char memberType;
```

So, may I know what is my problem ? Or is there any code you need to know, let me know and  I'll edit my post then.
And 1 more is that I have to use String n instead of this.name = name to be able to work.

//  Set method

```
public static void setName(String n)
{
    name = n;
}

public static void setAge(int a)
{
    age = a;
}

public static void setIcNo(String ic)
{
    icNo = ic;
}

public static void setPhoneNo(String phone)
{
    phoneNo = phone;
}

public static void setAddress(String a)
{
    address = a;
}

public static void setDate(java.util.Date d)
{
    date = d;
}
public static void setExpiryDate(java.util.Date expDate)
{
    expiryDate = expDate;
}

public static void setTrialClass(int tc)
{
    trialClass = tc;
}

public static void setMemberType(char mt)
{
    memberType = mt;
}
```

//  Get method

```
public static String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public static int getAge()
{
    return age;
}

public static String getIcNo()
{
    return icNo;
}

public static String getPhoneNo()
{
    return phoneNo;
}

public static String getAddress()
{
    return address;
}

public static java.util.Date getDate()
{
    return date;
}

public static java.util.Date getExpiryDate()
{
    return expiryDate;
}

public static int getTrialClass()
{
    return trialClass;
}

public static double getJoiningFees()
{
    return joiningFees;
}

public static char getMemberType()
{
    return memberType;
}
```

Comment: Try creating an instance of `Member` instead of setting everything to static. Also, try learning Java before implementing the fixes your IDE tells you.

Comment: You are invoking Member.<method> which means you are trying to invoke a method without creating instance. For that the method need to be static. Create `Member m = new Member();` and then invoke like `m.getName(); `

Comment: Oh ya, thanks I forgot about the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to re-read the OOP section of your book mate. You need to create an instance  of Member.

```
Member member1 = new Member() ;
member1.setName("Chris");
```

This will probably mean nothing  to you so i really suggest reading about OOP first. Possibly even choose a different book.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/

Comment: Thanks, my code is so messy that I forget I didn't do an instance for it.